# How to adjust only Image icon in Navigation menu?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface, c#-3.0

I created Navigation menu. 
  In my navigation menu and I want to move only image icon.
  I tried but it is not moving exactly and whole division is moving. 
  I need to move only image icon from top to bottom.

[image: This is menu]

Thank you ...

Comment: You should also show some code and describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: hi tomas  i updated my post ....

Comment: clearly, i mentioned Tomasz .. I need to move Image adjustment. i need to move little bit bottom...

Comment: try padding-top css rule on the image.